# Installing driver for USB wifi adapter - completely lost

Tags: wireless, usb

I have three separate USB wifi adapters. All work in Windows. One says Linux compatible on the package (I'll call it "A"). It even comes with Linux drivers.

I used lsusb.

I see the two of the adapters, but not the one which specifies linux compatability and came with drivers.

I copied the drivers for "A" to a folder in my home folder I called wifi. I clicked properties on install.sh and clicked 'allow executing'. I executed it and it seemed to install some drivers, I was asked for my password twice. But still, the USB is not showing up in lsusb.

The other two usb adapters (I don't really care which one I use, as long as it works) show up on lsusb. How do I install the drivers?

One is an Asus (Broadcom BCM43526)
The other just says ID: 2001:331a D-Link Corp. (Its the Death Star looking USB3 usb wifi adapters..Yes, its pretty cool).

So, I know you all get asked this many times a day, but I am stuck on this one. I would love to use the one that has the drivers on the dvd. But, I will use any of them.

I am using the latest version of Ubuntu Mate. Bionic Beaver 18.04.
The motherboard is an Asrock970m Pro3 (crap)
CPU: FX-6350, not overclocked. (crap too, but it was sitting around).
8 gigs ram. Want to use this rig as a media server/file server.

In an semi-related issue, I have an Nvidia GTX760 in here and its not giving me any option to install the proprietary drivers from Nvidia.

Thanks again, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you suggest I reinstall an earlier and more stable release? If so, which one?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos  for what else you need to do to diagnose your WiFi problem.

Answer (score 3):

**For the ASUS BCM43526** try:

In `terminal`...

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms
```

**For the D-Link DWA-192**:

In `terminal`...

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential git

sudo git clone https://github.com/zebulon2/rtl8814au.git
```

create `dkms.conf` in the rt8814au folder, and add these lines...

```
# rtl8814AU-4.3.21_17997.20160531
#
#
PACKAGE_NAME="rtl8814au"
PACKAGE_VERSION="4.3.21_17997.20160531"
MAKE[0]="'make' all KVER=${kernelver}"
BUILT_MODULE_NAME[0]="8814au"
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="/updates/dkms"
AUTOINSTALL="YES"
REMAKE_INITRD="NO"
```

then...

```
sudo cp -r rtl8814au /usr/src/rtl8814au-4.3.21
sudo dkms add rtl8814au/4.3.21
sudo dkms build rtl8814au/4.3.21
sudo dkms install rtl8814au/4.3.21
dkms status
```

**note: you may have to adjust the version numbers if a newer release exists**

Comment: Ok, status is that its installed and added. Now what?

Comment: @DanL Does the `dkms status` command show both drivers as installed? If so, reboot, and your ASUS & D-Link should be working. Report back. Don't do my and chili555's answers at the same time. Just pick one.

Comment: Your method worked! Thank you for the info. I don't know what was going on with chili555's method, but I tried it multiple times and reinstalled the OS 3 times to no avail. I did it your way and it works fine. Thank you for the help. You too chili555, thanks for trying.

Comment: @DanL. Please remember to accept my answer if it was helpful, by clicking on the grey checkmark icon next to my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

With a temporary working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/ulli-kroll/rtl8814au.git
cd rtl8814au
make
sudo make installfw
sudo insmod rtl8814au.ko
```

Please tell us if the device is now working as I will have further instructions to add in an edit.

**EDIT**: We see this message in your `make`:

> Makefile:976: "Cannot use CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION=y, please install
>   libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel"

Please do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libelf-dev
```

A series of dependencies will also be installed. Follow with:

```
cd rtl8814au
make clean
make
sudo insmod rtl8814au.ko
```

Post any errors.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76990/discussion-on-answer-by-chili555-installing-driver-for-usb-wifi-adapter-comple).