# D-Link DWA-182 Rev.A

Tags: drivers, wireless, broadcom, d-link

Is there a way to use the D-link DWA-182 rev A with modern Ubuntu versions? The D-link site only has Linux drivers for rev C and D.

Here's the output of`lsusb` for the device:

```bash
$ lsbusb
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 2001:3101 D-Link Corp. DWA-182 AC1200 DB Wireless Adapter (rev.A1) [Broadcom BCM43526]
```

Comment: `lsusb` should return an alphanumeric code in the format of two sets of four characters separated by a colon. Example: `04a9:176b` This number will determine the exact chipset for Rev A. Please edit and include this number.

Comment: updated with ID. 2001:3101

Comment: Thanks. It's not clear if this one is supported but you can try installing the broadcom sta dkms driver: `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms` If everything goes well, reboot and if it's not working immediately, of course, unplug it and plug it back in and if it doesn't automatically come on, run `sudo modprobe wl` and if it still doesn't work, unplug it and plug it back in and then run `sudo modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma` and then `sudo modprobe wl`

Comment: Looks like my kernel isn't supported.
`$ sudo apt install broadcom-sta-dkms`

`Building initial module for 6.0.6-76060006-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-6.0.6-76060006-generic is not 
supported`

Comment: Ah well, the device id doesn't show that it's supported anyhow. It looks like this chip is unsupported.

Comment: Even though that error appears to be unrelated.

Comment: According to [this thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2414077#post_13842643), it wasn't supported back in 2019 and the chip has been around since 2012. It's pretty weird to not have support but the device id doesn't show up anywhere.

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1027538/167115) mentions the broadcom 43526 but doesn't mention the device id. Supposedly, the answer worked but the OP had more than one adapter and it looks like the answer probably applied to the other USB adapter.

Comment: I vaguely remember trying something with the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package in the past but I dont remember whether it solved this problem. For anyone else having the same problem, this thread may be useful: https://www.linux.org/threads/pop-os-doesnt-detect-my-wifi-adapter-after-i-updated-to-latest-version.35861/page-4

Comment: Yeah, they had a different device id. PCI card it looks like. I thought maybe give it a try because that last answer wasn't clear on what worked (and what didn't) but if dkms is having trouble installing that driver, it's probably not worth the effort just to find out that it doesn't even support the card.

Comment: Please see my post #5 here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2414077 I suggest that you purchase a different device.